# Spring MVC Page Getting PageNotFound Error: "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/welcomepage.jsp] in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

To all:

I know this issue has been presented in umpteen different ways, but I as a newbie to Spring Java, none of what I've seen here or anywhere else has resolved my particular situation. So, as best I can, here's what's happening:

As a learning exercise I've tried to write a simple Spring MVC application. All I want to do is display a JSP page with one parameter. The error I have gotten every time has been:

**WARN 12020 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/welcomepage.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'**

As another post suggested, I created a WebAppInitializer class, but its onStartup event doesn't fire off at all:

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
package dau.mydata.mydata;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;  
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;  
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;  

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  

        System.out.println(">>> WebAppInitializer.onStartup() fired");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  

        ctx.register(SpringConfig.class);               // Put your config class name here  

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
        dynamic.addMapping("/");  
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  

   }  

}
```

My configuration class appears to have all the correct, required annotations:

**SpringConfig.java**

```
package dau.mydata.mydata;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("dau.mydata.mydata")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {         // new for Spring 5

    @Bean  
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {  
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();  
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");  
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
        return resolver;  
    }

}
```

The POM file has the JSTL library and the Tomcat Jasper reference:

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dau.mydata</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>my-data</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                    <version>20180130</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- dispatcher servlet -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and the @RequestMapping fires correctly for the "/" but not when I specify the "/mvc" (intentionally chosen string) for the URL:

**BasicController.java**

```
package dau.mydata.mydata;

// Had to drop these in myself since IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support Spring for free...
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

// For the flight data local web service
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

// JSON support
import org.json.*;

// MVC support
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
@RestController
public class BasicController {

    // Globals for getAllFlights
    private String server = "http://localhost";         // local server on 80?
    private RestTemplate rest;
    private HttpHeaders headers;
    private HttpStatus status;

    @RequestMapping("/")                                // catch anything
    public String displaySplashPage() {
        System.out.println(">>> displaySplashPage() fired");
        String outline = "<div style='font-size:18pt; font-family:sans-serif;'>";
        outline += getAllFlights();
        outline += "</div>";

        return outline;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/mvc")                                // catch anything
    public ModelAndView displaySplashPageMvc(String welcome) {
        System.out.println(">>> displaySplashPageMvc() fired");
        ModelAndView mvout = new ModelAndView("welcomepage");          // name of the JSP page
        mvout.addObject("welcomestring", welcome);

        return mvout;
    }

    public String getAllFlights() {
        System.out.println(">>> getAllFlights() fired");
        String fltdata = get("/flights.php");
        JSONObject fltjson = new JSONObject(fltdata);
        JSONArray fltjsonarray = fltjson.getJSONArray("flights");

        String outline = ">>> length: " + fltjsonarray.length() + "<br>";

        for (int n = 0; n < fltjsonarray.length(); n++) {
            //JSONObject item = fltjsonarray.getJSONObject(n);
            String flightNum = fltjsonarray.getJSONObject(n).getString("flightNum");
            outline += flightNum + "<br>";
        }

        return outline;
    }

    // routines from elsewhere

    public String get(String uri) {
        System.out.println(">>> get() fired");
        // set the globals to retrieve HTTP data
        this.rest = new RestTemplate();
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("Accept", "*/*");

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = rest.exchange(server + uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
        this.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCode());

        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }

    public void setStatus(HttpStatus status) {
        System.out.println(">>> setStatus() fired");
        this.status = status;
    } 

}
```

Incidentally, I tried @RestController by itself, as well as how it's shown above, with @Controller - no difference in the result.

Finally, here's the JSP page:

**welcomepage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring MVC Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>MVC Test</h2>
        <h2>
            ${welcomestring}
        </h2>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using NetBeans 8.2 to edit and compile this project. Here's the project file structure:

```
my-data
---Web Pages
------WEB-INF
---------pages
------------welcomepage.jsp
---Source Packages
------dau.mydata.mydata
---------BasicController.java
---------MyDataApplication.java
---------SpringConfig.java
---------WebAppInitializer.java
...
---Project Files
------pom.xml
```

It seems to me that for something that should ostensibly be so simple, there are a LOT of moving parts to make a simple MVC page work.

What am I missing? I'm hoping the correction is, perhaps, a one- or two-line change.

Thanks!

Comment: can you try after removing "@RestController" from BasicController?

Comment: The fact is you are using spring boot, Spring Boot uses embedded tomcat and embedded tomcat and JSP aren't friends. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations. At least you should use a `war` instead of a `jar`. However I strongly suggest to ditch JSP and use something like Thymeleaf instead. Also you are using Spring Boot but you are trying very hard not too use spring boot and your configuration is actually disabling parts of it.